# Remove "New" button when adding opportunity contact roles

Tags: page-layout, opportunitycontactrole

When adding a new contact role to an opportunity, there's a "New" button available in the contact lookup menu. Problem is, if you create a new contact this way, it's not associated with any account and it bypasses all other validation rules/required fields you might have set up. Is there any way to remove this button from the layout?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called [Quick Create](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=basics_creating_records_with_quick_create.htm). You can disable it in Setup | Customize | User Interface. You can also read more about the effects of turning this off in [000005155](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000005155&language=en_US).

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Setup
2. quick search "User Interface"
3. Un-check the "Show Quick Create" checkbox.